# How to control allowed HTML tags in WMD Editor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wmd, wysiwym

I am trying to some-how set the valid HTML tags and attributes users would be able to use in [WMD Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/) in [my site](http://forumsr.gxopen.com). For example, I want to forbid the user to directly set the font size, color, typeface and so on, which is trivial to do with the default settings typing something like:

```
<span style="font-size: 45px; color:#FF0000">Some intrusive text here</span>.
```

I think the way to implement this is through the "wmd_options", but I have not found any documentation or reference regarding this, giving the fact that the 'Options demo' seems to be the only public documentation and it does not show how should I do what I have described above.

I've send this same question to support@attacklab.net but didn't get any reply. As stackoverflow uses this editor someone reading this or maybe [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) knows the answer ;)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you wanted to know how it can be done via the [wmd editor](http://wmd-editor.com) but you must surely realize a javascript editor is not going to stop people on this.

If you want to know how some of the tags are stripped on the server on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), you might want to take a look at [this](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html).